# SpringBoot @RequestParam MultipartFile will translate @RequestParam String in string concatenation

Tags: string, spring-boot, multipartform-data, spring-restcontroller, spring-rest

I've found this strange behavior during developing a SpringBoot controller.

SpringBoot version in pom.xml

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.3.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
```

Create a controller

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/route")
@Slf4j
public class Api {

    @PostMapping
    public ResponseEntity<Void> createFromCsv(@RequestParam("label") String label,
                                              @RequestParam MultipartFile csvFile) {

        log.debug("label {}", label);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.OK);
    }
 }
```

If I make a post sending value like this

[image: post to controller]

In my back end code when the data will arrive and manipulate by spring the @RequestParam except the multipart file are completely wrong

[image: back end debugging]

As you can see the value of label that present a space character during post is duplicate in my controller.
This not happen if I remove the MultipartFile from controller

**UPDATE**

I've seen that the additional RequestParam from signature will be put inside the requestMultipartParam

Analyzing the httpServletRequest this is what I'have

[image: http servlet request param map]

As you can see the value are duplicated.

Comment: How you are testing this?

Comment: @sankar via swagger. But I found the problem also by angular app.

Comment: @ad3luc I am not able to reproduce this

Comment: @MaruthiAdithya so you aren't affected by this?
Are you using same spring version?

Comment: @MaruthiAdithya the spring version is already written in top of my question.

Comment: Just update the spring version and see if problem persists. I am not seeing any problem with code . @RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file  .Just pass the variable name for multipart file and see if it helps.